# How can I resize QTableView row according to specific cell value?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtableview

I want to resize the row height according to a specific column value. For example, the table I want to change is here:

[image: the table I want to change is here]

At row 10, row height is resized by the third column value. But at row 11 it is resized by the second column value. I want to resize row height by only the third column value. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

This is my code for this `QTableView`

```cpp
ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
ui->tableView->hideColumn(0);
ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
ui->tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView { font-size: 18pt; color:#002B5B; font-weight: bold; }");
```

[image]

Comment: You mean "adjust row height to the height of the last cell in that row"?

Comment: By default it is disabled since calculating optimal width for a column is extremely time consuming in many cases. Double click on border of rows in labels column forces optimal column height.

Comment: @pptaszni they want me to do that yes. I hide some 2 column for you to reduce complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually tried it myself, but from looking at the Qt source code (in particular the source code for `QTableView::rowHeight(int) const` and `QHeaderView::sectionSizeFromContents(int) const`), it looks like you could do something like:

```
const int addressColumnLogicalIndex = 1;  // i.e. 2nd column in the table
const int fixedRowHeight = 18;  // or whatever fixed height you want the address-column to use
model()->setHeaderData(addressColumnLogicalIndex, Qt::Vertical, QSize(0, fixedRowHeight), Qt::SizeHintRole);
```

Comment: I just tried this and it's like what i want. I actually added a new screen shot and I'll explain more clearly. I want to resize row automaticly if third column has multiple value. However, in the second screen shot the second column value has several line. If so the second cell should look like Adana Emniyet... I hope it was clear.